# Styling up/down arrows in table rows

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 2 columns. one column is data and the second is up/down arrows.

the up arrow should not display on the first row and the down arrow should not display for the last row. I tried this for a long time but nothing happens. The function is called but the arrows always display.
anyone can help?

```
function reset_updown_mbp()
{
    $('tr > td > img[src="up.png"]').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('tr > td > img[src="up.png"]:first').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('tr > td > img[src="dn.png"]').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('tr > td > img[src="dn.png"]:last').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `id` to your table, for sample:

```
<table id="myTable">
...
</table>
```

And your javascript, try using `.hide()` and `.show()` functions:

```
<script>

    function reset_updown_mbp()
    {       
        $('#myTable img[src*="up.png"]').show();
        $('#myTable img[src*="up.png"]:first').hide();
        $('#myTable img[src*="dn.png"]').show()
        $('#myTable img[src*="dn.png"]:last').hide();
    }

    // and remember to call the function
    $(document).ready(function() {

        reset_updown_mbp();

    });

</script>
```

In the jquery filter, I'm not sure how is your html code and for this reason I use `*=`, because it `Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.`

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: did not work. any idea how i can add the table id to this function? maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed `reset_updown_mbp` method on `document.ready`?